# SSL handshake failure in one task and successful in another while server is on same domain and same port

Tags: java, ssl, sslhandshakeexception, java-security

In my web app i have two different task in which i am trying to connect to two different URL's (which are on same domain and same Port). For one task SSL handshake is successful and i am getting response but for another i am getting SSL handshake failure. I am not able to understand that what is the issue. 
Java version is 1.8

Below is my code for SSL->
  // Install the all-trusting trust manager

```
     try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
}
```

Open Connection is working successfully.

```
public ClientHttpRequest(URL url) throws IOException {
        this((HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection());
    }
```

I am getting exception here in connection.getOutputStream()->

```
protected void connect() throws IOException {
        if (os == null) os = connection.getOutputStream();
    }
```

Kindly help .

Comment: If the difference is only the path of the URL then likely one of the URL's requires a client certificate while the other don't.

Comment: for both the URL's domain name is same  and rest of the URL is different. How can i check that if other URL doesn't require any client certificate because it is using that above mentioned same piece of code.

Comment: Please add `-Djavax.net.debug=all` system property to your client and come back with the trace. It should tell us what's happening.

Comment: I added this property in Tomcat Java options  but not able to find any stack trace. Is there any other file where i should add this property?